# String array length C++ issue?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I've understood that string arrays end with a '\0' symbol. So, the following code should print 0, 1, 2 and 3. (Notice I'm using a range-based for() loop).

```
$ cat app.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    int main(){
        char s[]="0123\0abc";
        for(char c: s) std::cerr<<"-->"<<c<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

But it does print the whole array, including '\0's.

```
$ ./app
-->0
-->1
-->2
-->3
-->
-->a
-->b
-->c
-->

$ _
```

What is happening here? Why is the string not considered to end with '\0'? Do C++ collections consider (I imagine C++11) strings differently than in classical C++?

Moreover, the number of characters in `"0123\0abc"` is 8. Notice the printout makes 9 lines!

(I know that `std::cout<<` runs fine, as well as `strlen()`, as well as `for(int i=s; s[i]; i++)`, etc., I know about the end terminator, that's not the question!).

Comment: `std::cout << "123\0abc"` would print `123`.

Comment: @Jarod42, obviously, that's not the question.

Comment: C-arrays can decays to pointer, but are different.

Comment: *"obviously"*. For me, both output are obvious too ;-) So trying to find your misunderstanding cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is of type `char [9]`, i.e. an array containing 9 `char`s (including the null terminator char '\0'). [Ranged-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) just iterators over all the 9 elements, the null terminator char `'\0'` is not considered  specially.

> Executes a for loop over a range.
>
> Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop
>   operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container.

`for(char c: s) std::cerr<<"-->"<<c<<std::endl;` produces code prototype equivalent to

```
{
  auto && __range = s ;
  auto __begin = __range ;         // get the pointer to the beginning of the array 
  auto __end = __range + __bound ; // get the pointer to the end of the array ( __bound is the number of elements in the array, i.e. 9 )
  for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    char c = *__begin;
    std::cerr<<"-->"<<c<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a `char[]` as `char s[] = "0123\0abc"` (a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)), `s` becomes a `char[9]`. The `\0` is included because it needs space too.

The range-based for-loop you use does not consider the `char[9]` as anything else than an array containing `char` with the extent `9` and will happily provide every element in the array to the inner workings of your loop. The `\0` is just one of the `char`s in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that `char` not necessarily needs to define a character only – it can be used to store *any arbitrary* 8-bit value (on some machines, char is wider, though, encountered one with a 16-bit char already – then there's no `int8_t` available...), although `signed char` or `unsigned char` – according to specific needs – should be preferred, as signedness of `char` is implementation defined (or even better: `int8_t` or `uint8_t` from `cstdint` header, provided they are available).

So your string literal actually is just an array of nine integral values (just as if you had created an int-array, only the type usually is narrower). A range based for loop will iterate over all of these nine 8-bit integers, and you get the output in your example.

These integral values only get a special meaning in specific contexts (functions), such as `printf`, `puts` or even [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), where they are then ***interpreted*** as characters. When used as C-strings, a 0 value inside such an array marks the end of the string – but this 0-character still is *part of* that string. For illustration: `puts` might look like this:

```
int puts(char const* str)
{
    while(!*str) // stops on encountering null character 
    {
        char c = *str;

        // + get pixel representation of c for console, e. g 'B' for 66
        // + print this pixel representation to current console position
        // + advance by one position on console

        ++str;
    }
    return 0; // non-negative for success, could return number of
              // characters output as well...
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good hint... Thanks. Actually, that 16-bit-char DSP already mentioned had sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)...

Comment: "Porting" heaven! :-) I've been in the same room as a machine that has "32 bits for everything" - "_char ... long ... fark it. I'll go with 32_".

Comment: @TedLyngmo Then that machine is not standard conformant - long long requires 64 bits! (Just joking...)

Comment: I'm sure that machine didn't ask anyone for permission - It was **the machine** after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Here **s** is an array of **char**, so it includes `\0` too.
  When you use `for(char c: s)`, the loop will search all `char` in the array.
  But in C, the definition tells us:

  > A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

  And

  > [...] The *length* of a *string* is the number of bytes ***preceding the null character*** and the *value* of a *string* is the sequence of the values of the contained characters...

  So, when you use C standard functions to print the array **s** as a string, you will see the result that you wanted. Example: `printf("%s", s);`
- *"the number of characters in "0123\0abc" is 8. Notice the printout makes 9 lines!"*

  Again, `printf("%s; Len = %d", s, strlen(s));` runs fine!

Comment: strlen returns size_t, so you must print it with `%zu`, not `%d`